# Create dataframe from RDD[class]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

There is an `RDD[Person]` in my spark code and I want to convert this rdd into `dataframe`. Person class is not a case class, it is a regular Scala class. I know with case class but I am unable to convert from regular scala class. Please help

Comment: If you can make this class a case class, that would be best solution. If you cannot _(maybe it is an external Java class)_, you can create an `Encoder` for any class, using **Kryo** _serialization_. But, take in mind that it may be slow.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez In my person class, there are 56 fields so I can't make it case class.

Answer (score 1):

The limitation for 22 fields in case classes was fixed in Scala 2.11. It's possible to create a case class with 22+ fields:

```
// 23 letters of the English alphabet
scala> case class Large(
     |   a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int,
     |   e: Int, f: Int, g: Int, h: Int,
     |   i: Int, j: Int, k: Int, l: Int,
     |   m: Int, n: Int, o: Int, p: Int,
     |   q: Int, r: Int, s: Int, t: Int,
     |   u: Int, v: Int, w: Int)
```

It works fine with the usual Spark DataFrame API:

```
  import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
  import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
  Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR) // Silencing trash
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder
    .master("local")
    .appName("test")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._
  val sc = spark.sparkContext

  case class Large(
                    a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int,
                    e: Int, f: Int, g: Int, h: Int,
                    i: Int, j: Int, k: Int, l: Int,
                    m: Int, n: Int, o: Int, p: Int,
                    q: Int, r: Int, s: Int, t: Int,
                    u: Int, v: Int, w: Int)

  val large = Large(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23)

  val lettersDF: DataFrame = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(large)).toDF()
  lettersDF.show()
```

But there are two limitations for case classes with 22+ fields: `Large.tupled` and `Large.unapply` are not accessible. Those methods don’t exist on `Large`.

If these limitations are crucial for you, there is a [workaround](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.3/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema) - programmatically specifying the schema.

Quotation from the official documentation:

> When case classes cannot be defined ahead of time (for example, the
>   structure of records is encoded in a string, or a text dataset will be
>   parsed and fields will be projected differently for different users),
>   a DataFrame can be created programmatically with three steps.
>
> - Create an RDD of Rows from the original RDD;
> - Create the schema represented by a StructType matching the structure of Rows in the RDD created in Step 1.
> - Apply the schema to the RDD of Rows via createDataFrame method provided by SparkSession.

Basically, you have to make a schema to the corresponding class and apply it to the rows. You can find the example in the link above.

HTH